# Performance fixed during profiling in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I was running a SignalR app hosted together with MVC5 and WebAPI and was using a library that handles connections to Redis behind actors abstraction.

When I first ran this app in IIS Express the time for a single Hub/API call was about 1 sec, while it should take only one trip to Redis.

When I started profiling in Visual Studio, each call took 5-10 msec - exactly the time for a Redis trip.

*The question is* what resources are kept during profiling and destroyed even during running in debug mode? It feels like outside profiling mode I reopen connections and initialize my library on every service call. Cannot find what is going on because during profiling it works as expected...

Update: default IIS 8 configuration is as slow as IIS Express

Comment: How is the IIS Application Pool configured?

Comment: Didn't change anything from default IIS Express configuration

Comment: You might try looking at that- perhaps try switching the StartMode to AlwaysRunning? I haven't played with Express in a while but it does sound like your guess is that the resources are being called on a per request basis and that is most likely to be related to the IIS configuration rather than your code.